# jquery mobile button inside CSS Dropdown Navigation bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a jquery mobile button to a dropdown navbar. I cannot however get the `<ul>` tag o style the mobile button. It seems whatever I try the jquery styling does not take effect. I have included a js fiddle.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li.right {
  float: right;
}
li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}
li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.fixed-nav-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<nav class="fixed-nav-bar">
  <ul data-role="listview" ">
      <li><a class="active " href="#home ">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news ">News</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown ">
        <a href="# " class="dropbtn ">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content ">
          <a href="# ">Link 1</a>
          <a href="# ">Link 2</a>
          <a href="# ">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="right ">
     
      <a id="Logout " class="ui-btn ui-icon-search ui-btn-icon-left ">Logout</a>
     
      </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

Here is a jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/w8xy7Lu2/

Comment: which button are you trying to add to the nav bar?

Comment: actually it s the power icon from jquery mobile

Comment: <a id="Logout" class="ui-btn ui-icon-search ui-btn-icon-left">Logout</a>

Comment: First of all, provide a _proper_ fiddle please. Embed external resources via the “External Resources” option on the left, instead of dumping the complete code into the HTML input area. And relative URLs for paths on _your_ system obviously don’t work in a fiddle either. Right now, none of those external resources get loaded.

Comment: my bad..i will add the resources for jquery mobile. The links arent intended to work. i am trying to get the jquery icon to show

Comment: @CBroe ..thnx for the advice. Actually organising the CSS and file and jquery resources has solved the issue. PLease see the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CBroe ..thnx for the advice. Actually organising the CSS and file and jquery resources has solved the issue. PLease see the jsfiddle